# How to add a "last" class to the last post in loop.php?

Tags: css, posts, loop

I need to add a "last" class to the last post that appears in loop.php.

Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

assuming you're using [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class):

```
add_filter('post_class', function($classes){
  global $wp_query;

  if(($wp_query->current_post + 1) == $wp_query->post_count)
    $classes[] = 'last';

  return $classes;
});
```

Comment: Does this work for the absolute last post in a paginated loop?

Comment: I think it should be `$found_posts` instead. [Codex Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64006/ShareX/2015-08/2015-08-12_19-10-25.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery addClass() when I style odd/even list items or similar. You could probably use it to achieve what you want too.

Example:

```
 $("#menu_side > ul > li:last-child").addClass("last");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not using jQuery. Also, using JavaScript to apply the class could cause the styling to display before the JavaScript loads, which would make it "flash off" and it wouldn't look pretty.